# redux-forms field level validation function triggers for every field it associated to and not just the changing field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-form

I am new to react. I am trying to implement the field level validation and want the validation function (myFunction in this case) to be triggered for the changing field and not all the field the function associated to which is occurring now.

```
<Field
    name="username"
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
    label="Username"
    validate={myFunction}
    warn={alphaNumeric}
  />
  <Field
    name="email"
    type="email"
    component={renderField}
    label="Email"
    validate={myFunction}
    warn={aol}
  />
```

myFunction:

```
const maxLength = max => value => && value.length > max ? `Must be ${max} characters or less` : undefined
```

[Reference](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/)

Is this possible in react to trigger it just for the changing field?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not possible as redux-forms pass all the values to validation function even if your function doesn't use it. So with any change all of the validation of all of the fields will be triggered anyway. See: https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/field.md/

Comment: ok, is there any alternative for that, like stop the validation as soon as it finds the first invalid Field?